# How to effectively undertake the study of a philosophical work?

Tags: critical-theory, rhetoric, hermeneutics, interpretation

I feel like this question gets posed a lot in different ways and was curious if it might be possible to formulate it narrowly enough to get answered here.

For the most part I think the answer is determined by the question -- in other words, you find someone who does understand and get them to explain it to you.

Of course even with a pair -- or ideally a mentor -- one still must tackle a text in isolation. The "someone who understands" is finally the author themselves.

How to prepare yourself to evaluate and interpret a philosophical text? I'm looking for a strategic vision here.

Beyond tactical things like reading secondary sources or finding a pair/mentor to study with; and even beyond spiritual qualities (a certain patience, caution, charity, &c). Although ideally strategies for evaluation/interpretation will have an impact on the tactics and spirit of a reading.

What long-term sort of *critical practices* can help support the structured, rigorous reading and evaluation of philosophical texts?

Comment: Purchase a good armchair, particularly of a rocking nature, and a good pipe. ;)

Comment: Stay away from alcoholic drinks to keep a sharp mind. Cut sugar and avoid too much meat in your diet.

Comment: Try to imagine the inner voice of the author which was whispering author what to write and how, but itself did not get onto the paper... Inverse read.

Comment: Do you mean to evaluate based on the author's context, or a modern one?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the best way to truly understand a work is to be a part of the ongoing discourse surrounding it -- i.e. try to find an opportunity to write about the work for an audience. Reading with the goal of communicating with others opens the opportunity for a much more rigorous approach.

This written dialectic is one of the fundamental activities of the philosophical community across history.